# Running Dual GridView Controls to show Summary / Details View

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got a query to display parts by serial numbers in one column and the number of processes they went through in the other column.

This data is dumped into a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control called `gvSummary`. It works OK now.

What I'd like to do is add a second [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control called `gvDetails` next to `gvSummary`, and replace all of the data in `gvSummary` with a control that will run a detail query for that particular part when it is clicked.

My plan of attack is to replace the text in the `Serial_Number` column (Column[0]) with something like the [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control, where the `NavigateUrl` specifies to call my **GetDetails** method by passing the text of the `Serial_Number`.

```
var table = GetPartsForTimePeriod();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
  string serialNumber = table.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim();
  var link = new HyperLink()
  {
    ID = string.Format("lnk{0}", serialNumber.Replace(' ', '_'))
  };
  link.Text = serialNumber;
  link.NavigateUrl = string.Format("GetDetails(\"{0}\"}", serialNumber);
  table.Rows[i][0] = link;
}
GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Issues:**

A HyperLink would require a page to load, and all I really want to do is fill this next query into the `gvDetails` control.

What is the right way to go about this? I generally code WinForms, and I can't think of the way to do this in ASP.NET.

Comment: There is a DetailsView control in ASP.Net that goes with a GridView. Are you aware of that and have you considered using it?

Comment: Nope. I wasn't even aware of that. It could be all I need.